# use two associations from a service to a Entitity in a class diagram is alowed?

Tags: spring, uml

I would like to know if is allow to use two associations in a class diagram: this is my example:
[image: example]

thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notably you have the attributes `interval` and `intervalListe` of type `MesureInterval` inside `MetierMesureInterval`. Probably you should remove them and use role names instead (see also https://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/).

[image]

Also you should get rid of the navigation arrows and `x`s. The multiplicity tells that already. They can be used in a draft sketch where you don't have role names and/or multiplicities.

Also note that I used the dot notation which tells that the role name is an owned property with the according role name (so making them superfluous in the attributes compartment).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. You might want to add some role information to each relationship illustrate what they are about, but beyond that this is fine.